# Airflow webserver launched via subprocess not dying on kill

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen, airflow

Using Python 3.6.1. I am emulating launching an `airflow webserver` from the command as a process using `subprocess.Popen`.

After doing some things, I later move to kill (or terminate) it.

```
webserver_process = subprocess.Popen(["airflow", "webserver"])
webserver_process.kill()
```

My understanding is that this will send a `SIGKILL` to the webserver, whose underlying `gunicorn` should shutdown immediately.

However, when I navigate to http://localhost:8080 I see that the webserver is still running. Similarly when I then run `sudo netstat -nlp|grep 8080` (I am using UNIX, and `airflow webserver` launches on port 8080), I discover:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

It's only when I kill the process manually using `sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp` that it finally dies.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python process returned by `airflow webserver` command actually calls `subprocess.Popen` to start `gunicorn` in a subprocess.

You can test this by calling webserver_process.pid, you'll notice that it's a different pid from the gunicorn master process pid.

Comment: Oh boy, turtles all the way down. I know I can shut down via the PID, but I was hoping for a way to do so inline without needing `sudo` or messing with file permissions.

Do you know if there is any methodology I can use in the internal API to initialize a shutdown?